# Are stomach noises (without additional symptoms) a cause for worry?

Tags: nutrition, stomach

For example, should I try to find a diet that does not cause these noises? Maybe the sounds are indication of non-optimal food combinations that has an impact on dietary value?

According to [1](http://www.foxnews.com/health/2015/03/30/noisy-stomach-normal-or-unhealthy/),[2](http://www.iffgd.org/site/manage-your-health/symptoms-causes/noisy-tummy) (and more) stomach noises are normal.

Answer (score 5):

Stomach rumbles, or to give them their proper name of [boborygmus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/borborygmi), are the movement of gas and fluid in the intestines. This is a normal thing. Most of the time they are not loud enough to be audible, but they can occasionally be heard without the aid of a stethoscope.

It can also occur with incomplete digestion causing excess gas, excess swallowing of air, or when your stomach is empty and you are hungry.

There are a few diseases that can cause rumbles, such as [persistent diarrhea, celiac disease, Crohn's disease.](http://www.rightdiagnosis.com/symptoms/borborygmi/common.htm) I would not worry overmuch over the occasional noise, but if there seems to be a lot of it, and possibly accompanied by other symptoms such as excess flatulence, diarrhea, pain, I would have it checked out by a medical professional.